# AJAX POST Request execute only first call on safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari

> $('#course_id').change(function() {

> ```
>    var courseid = $(this).val();
>   getuniqueid(courseid);
>   //alert(courseid);
> ```

> });

> function getuniqueid(courseid){

> ```
>   if (courseid == '0')
>   {
>       alert("Please select the Course.");
>       
>       document.getElementById("course_id").value = "<?php echo $id ?>";
>       document.getElementById("course_id").focus();
>       return false;
>       
>   }
>
>   $.ajax({
>       
>        type: "POST",
>       url: 'createuniqueid.php',
>        data: { 
>           courseid:courseid
>           
>           },
>       datatype:'json',
>           
>       cache: false,
>        success: function( data ) {
>           //alert(data);
>           $('#custom').val(data);
>           console.log("success");
>       }
>    });
> ```
>
> }

> function coupon_submit(elm){
>
> ```
>   var sender_name = document.getElementById("sender_name").value;
>    var sender_email_id = document.getElementById("sender_email_id").value;
>    var receiver_name = document.getElementById("receiver_name").value;
>    var receiver_email_id= document.getElementById("receiver_email_id").value;
>
>    var courseid = document.getElementById("course_id").value;
>   var uniqueid = document.getElementById("custom").value;
>   
>    
>   $.ajax({
>       
>        type: "POST",
>        url: "datastring.php",
>        data: { sender_name: sender_name,
>            sender_email_id: sender_email_id,
>            receiver_name: receiver_name,
>           receiver_email_id:receiver_email_id,
>           courseid:courseid,
>           uniqueid:uniqueid
> ```

> ```
>           },
> ```

> ```
>        cache: false,
>        success: function( data ) {
>           alert(data);
>           console.log("success....");
>       },
>       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown,data) {
>        console.log("error. textStatus: %s  errorThrown: %s", textStatus, errorThrown);
> ```

> ```
>       }
>    });
> ```
>
> }

> 

It works fine on chrome, IE, Firefox but not on Safari. On Safari it executes only first AJAX call.
I need to call first getuniqueid and then coupon_submit. But for debugging process I placed coupon_submit function's code in getuniqueid function, the code of datastring.php get executed. Means it executes first AJAX call only.
Appriciate any help in advance!!

Comment: Please edit your question and use code formatting instead of quotation. The code is hard to read this way.

Comment: Yes, I did just after I published and saw that it's not proper. I am first time to put the question here. Thanks